# Converting string/numerical data to categorical format in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

I have a very large csv file that I have converted to a Pandas dataframe, which has string and integer/float values.  I would like to change this data to categorical format in order to try and save some memory. I am basing this idea off of the documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/categorical.html

My dataframe looks like the following:

```
    clean_data_measurements.head(20)

        station         date    prcp    tobs
    0   USC00519397 1/1/2010    0.08    65
    1   USC00519397 1/2/2010    0.00    63
    2   USC00519397 1/3/2010    0.00    74
    3   USC00519397 1/4/2010    0.00    76
    5   USC00519397 1/7/2010    0.06    70
    6   USC00519397 1/8/2010    0.00    64
    7   USC00519397 1/9/2010    0.00    68
    8   USC00519397 1/10/2010   0.00    73
    9   USC00519397 1/11/2010   0.01    64
    10  USC00519397 1/12/2010   0.00    61
    11  USC00519397 1/14/2010   0.00    66
    12  USC00519397 1/15/2010   0.00    65
    13  USC00519397 1/16/2010   0.00    68
    14  USC00519397 1/17/2010   0.00    64
    15  USC00519397 1/18/2010   0.00    72
    16  USC00519397 1/19/2010   0.00    66
    17  USC00519397 1/20/2010   0.00    66
    18  USC00519397 1/21/2010   0.00    69
    19  USC00519397 1/22/2010   0.00    67
    20  USC00519397 1/23/2010   0.00    67
```

It is precipitation data which goes on another 2700 rows. Since it is all of the same category (station number), it should be convertible to categorical format which will save processing time. I am just unsure of how to write the code. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Excuse me, why is categorical format saving processing time?

Comment: Also, what's wrong with `clean_data_measurements["station"] = clean_data_measurements["station"].astype("category")`?

Comment: Thanks ytu for your code, it is a clean solution and it works. A friend had recommended this idea to me, apparently, categorical data take less memory and computations are faster, this idea is supported in the documentation I referenced
/The categorical data type is useful in the following cases:

A string variable consisting of only a few different values. Converting such a string variable to a categorical variable will save some memory, see here./

I am incorporating what you suggested into my larger code.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can convert object to category data by using `factorize`

```
objectdf=df.select_dtypes(include='object')

df.loc[:,objectdf.columns]=objectdf.apply(lambda x : pd.factorize(x)[0])
df
Out[452]: 
    station  date  prcp  tobs
0         0     0  0.08    65
1         0     1  0.00    63
2         0     2  0.00    74
3         0     3  0.00    76
5         0     4  0.06    70
6         0     5  0.00    64
7         0     6  0.00    68
8         0     7  0.00    73
9         0     8  0.01    64
10        0     9  0.00    61
11        0    10  0.00    66
12        0    11  0.00    65
13        0    12  0.00    68
14        0    13  0.00    64
15        0    14  0.00    72
16        0    15  0.00    66
17        0    16  0.00    66
18        0    17  0.00    69
19        0    18  0.00    67
20        0    19  0.00    67
```

You can try this as well.

```
for y,x in zip(df.columns,df.dtypes):
    if x == 'object':
        df[y]=pd.factorize(df[y])[0]
    elif x=='int64':
        df[y]=df[y].astype(np.int8)
    else:
        df[y]=df[y].astype(np.float32)
```