# How to find the most-matching pair with respect to the target in python?

Tags: python, type-conversion, data-conversion

Each row of this table is showing the type of interaction that a unique molecule has with a bunch of specific amino acid residues. The first row is the target molecule, I want to find a molecule that replicates the target the most.

| Met1160 | Ala1108 | Val1092 | Met1211 | Asp1222 | Ala1226 | Ala1221 | Tyr1230 | Arg1208 | Asp1164 | Ile1084 | Tyr1159 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CHB | "Pi-Si, Pi-Al" | Pi-Al | "Pi-Si, Pi-Su" | CHB | Pi-Al | Pi-Al | Pi-Pi | CaHB | Pi-An | Pi-Al | Pi-Pi |
| CHB |  |  |  | CHB |  |  | "Pi-Pi, Pi-An" |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | Pi-Su |  |  | Pi-Al | Pi-Pi |  |  |  |  |
|  | Pi-Al | Pi-Al | Pi-Su |  |  | Pi-Al | Pi-Pi | Pi-Al |  |  |  |
|  | Pi-Al | Pi-Al | "Pi-Si, Pi-Su" |  |  | Pi-Al | Pi-Pi | CHB | CHB | "CHB, Pi-Al" | Pi-Pi |
| Pi-Su |  |  | Pi-Su |  |  | Pi-Al | "Pi-Pi, Un" | "CHB, Un" |  | "CHB, Pi-Al" |  |
| CHB |  |  |  | CHB |  |  | "CHB, Pi-Pi" |  | Pi-An |  |  |
|  |  |  | "Pi-Su, Pi-Al" |  |  |  | Pi-Pi | CHB | CHB |  |  |
| CHB |  | Pi-Al | Pi-Su |  |  | Pi-Al | Pi-Pi | Pi-Al | Pi-An | CHB |  |
|  |  | Pi-Al | Pi-Su |  |  | Pi-Al | Pi-Pi | "CHB, Pi-Al" | "Pi-An, Un" |  |  |
| CHB |  | Pi-Al | "Pi-Su, Pi-Al" |  |  | Pi-Al | Pi-Pi | Pi-Al | Pi-An | CHB |  |
| CHB |  |  |  | CHB |  |  | "CHB, Pi-Pi, Pi-An" |  |  | CHB |  |
|  | Pi-Al | Pi-Al | "Pi-Su, PiAl, Al" |  |  | Al | "CHB, Pi-Pi" |  | CHB | CHB |  |
|  | Pi-Al | Pi-Al | "Pi-Si, Pi-Su" |  |  | Pi-Al | Pi-Pi |  | Un | CHB |  |
|  | Pi-Al | Pi-Al | "Pi-Su, Pi-Al" |  |  |  | Pi-Pi | CHB | CHB | "CHB, Pi-Al" |  |
|  |  |  | Pi-Su |  |  | Pi-Al | "CHB, Pi-Pi" |  |  | "CHB, Pi-Al" |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  | "CHB, Pi-An" | CHB | CHB | Pi-Si | Pi-Pi |
| CHB |  |  | "Pi-Su, Pi-Al" |  | Pi-Al | Pi-Al | Pi-Pi |  | CHB |  | Pi-An |
| Un | Pi-Al | Pi-Al | Pi-Su |  |  | Pi-Al | Pi-Pi |  |  | CHB |  |
| "Pi-Su, Pi-Al" | Pi-Al | Pi-Al | "Pi-Su, Pi-Al" |  | Pi-Al | Pi-Al | Pi-Pi |  | CHB | "CHB, Pi-Si" |  |
| CHB | Pi-Al | Pi-Al | "Pi-Su, Pi-Al" |  | Pi-Al | Pi-Al | Pi-Pi |  | CHB | "CHB, Pi-Al" |  |
|  | Pi-Al | Pi-Al | "Pi-Su, Pi-Al" | Un |  |  | Pi-Pi |  |  |  | "CHB, Un" |
| CHB |  |  | "Pi-Su, Pi-Al" |  | Pi-Al | Pi-Al | Pi-Pi |  | CHB |  | Pi-An |
|  |  | Pi-Al |  |  |  |  | Pi-Pi |  | CHB | CHB |  |
| CHB | Pi-Al | Pi-Al | Pi-Su |  |  | Pi-Al | Pi-Pi | CHB | "CHB, Un" | Pi-Si |  |
| CHB |  | Pi-Al | "Pi-Si, Pi-Su" |  |  |  | Pi-Pi | Pi-Al | Pi-An | CHB | CHB |
|  |  |  | Pi-Su | CHB |  | Pi-Al | "CHB, Pi-Pi" |  | "CHB, Un" |  |  |
| CHB |  |  | "Pi-Su, Pi-Al" |  | Pi-Al | Pi-Al | "CHB, Pi-Pi" |  | CHB |  |  |
|  | Pi-Al | Pi-Al | "Pi-Si, Pi-Su" |  |  | Pi-Al | Pi-Pi |  |  | CHB |  |
|  | Pi-Al | Pi-Al | "Pi-Si, Pi-Su" |  |  |  | Pi-Pi | CHB | "CHB, Pi-An" | CHB | CHB |
|  | Pi-Al | Pi-Al | "Pi-Si, Pi-Su" |  |  | Pi-Al | Pi-Pi |  | CHB | "CHB, Un" | Un |

For the numerical calculation, I have used is:

```
import scipy.spatial
ary = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(df2, df1, metric='correlation')
df2[ary==ary.min()]
```

But here I don't have data in numerical format. How can I utilize python for doing that, when the data is not numeric? should I convert to numerical form, if so how?

Comment: Honestly, this question is going over my head. Can you explain what you by the best match? Say you have CHB what would be the best match for that?

Comment: By best match, I mean the row with the highest number of matching cells comparing with the first row.

Comment: This looks like a nearest neighbour problem to me. Does this help https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html ? To convert the strings into numeric data, you could use factorize. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51372462/converting-string-numerical-data-to-categorical-format-in-pandas.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count the matches, you can use string comparisons:

for example, you can check in the value in one column in in another one. You can use `split` to remove the commas. Then go row by row and count the positive matches.

```
>>> a= "CHB"
>>> b= "CHB, Un"

>>> a in b
True

>>> b in a
False

>>>b.split(",")[0] in a  
True

>>>b.split(",")[1] in a
False
```